# Excel versions for pop-up user forms?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, userform

This is a very simple question from me.

I have inserted some user forms in **Excel 2013** which have VBA code in them.

Some of the users have a very old version of Excel (such as Microsoft Excel 2003/2006).

I would like to know, will my user forms work in these older versions? I worry because back in 2003, I believe they were not called 'user forms' and therefore some functions may be disabled.

I cannot find a clear answer anywhere so a response here would help a lot.

Comment: No way for us to know without guessing. You can check for compatability issues `File -> Export -> Change File Type -> Excel 97-2003 Workbook`.

Comment: After Excel 95 was the change from dialog sheets to userforms I think.  It really depends on the exact code you used though - not so much the forms themselves but whether you rely on any post-2003 features.

Comment: I see no chance to answer this question at all. You will need to test it in the specific version.

Comment: Forget Userforms. There are lot of formulas which work in 2007+ but not in 2003. If it is just showing the userform that is troubling you then that is not a problem for 2003+ Excel. As for people using any version before 2003, they should be cryopreserved. They will be awesome specimens in the near future :|

Comment: The best way to cater to all versions is to develop your application in the lowest version so that it can work in all versions. Get a copy of Excel 2003 and recreate everything from scratch in that. This is mostly going to be a trial and error method.\

Comment: A systematic difference: Excel versions before 9.0 knew only *modal*userforms,  later versions (Excel 2000+/Windows) allow to show them *modeless*, too. Another example: `RefEdit` controls should be used only in modal userforms, otherwise you risk an immediate app crash.

Answer (score 0):

Userforms were introduced in Excel 5 back last century so there will be no problem there. You are more likely to hit problems with specific functions in the sheets, or with 64bit/32 bit versions. (And the idea that 2003 is a long time ago is cracking me up - we have one in-house program written in VB version 3 in 1993 still running)